# Getting the sum of second column where column A contains specific characters but exclude a certain letter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this setup in my worksheet

```
First     Second
ABXX      1
ABXX      2
ABCXX     10
ABXX      3
ABCXX     20
```

where AB and ABC are static
and the XX are numbers

---

and i need to do the following in a single cell (cell 1)

If column 1 contains AB, get the sum of its 2nd column

---

and do this on another cell (cell 2)

if column 1 contains ABC, get the sum of its 2nd column

---

im using this formula `=SUMIF(A:A,"*AB*",B:B)`

but the problem is it also includes ABC because it also contains the letters "AB"

is there a way to go around this?

Comment: Are there always two numbers, i.e. `XX`?

Comment: yes there is always 2 numbers at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If there are always two digits at the end*, then perhaps just use `?` to match a single character:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"AB??",B:B)
```

and

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"ABC??",B:B)
```

Comment: thanks this worked. i thought it wouldnt since the question mark may also track the letter "C"

Comment: Right, it does, but `AB??` does not match ABCXX, which is 5 letters long. This is why this only works if there are always two digits at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (assuming you only have ABC and AB in your column) :

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(A:A,3)="ABC"=TRUE)*B:B)
```

and

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(A:A,3)="ABC"=FALSE)*B:B)
```